# The alert() method is blocked on the website I have made a script for, is there a workaround for this?

Tags: javascript, console, alert

The basic `alert("some text")` is blocked/and any script using it will not run.  Is it possible to still make an alert even with it blocked?

Ideas I have thought of:

Making an embedded page and executing it there if that is possible.  If so, how?
If you have any other ideas, please reply.

*This script is being executed via the javascript:(javascript code) in the bookmarks/console*

Website is blooket.com/play
Script is:

```
function _script() { alert("this bit is to long to post") } var _OfBd98M25d; var _pX0za = "aBmXhswQwkder8B"; var _f8H76 = "TmvaxZWhYfU3pG8"; var _ki90a = "HaEMZUm65VPn53K"; var _st5sg = "XdsD4RwvSVXhFKM"; var _st1f3 = "NXG8cjTUfDTyZED"; var _o9hs5 = "X3QTxVLan2ZL94H"; var _st614 = "CNq7gKAZJbDhHU2"; var _osp12 = "tXG3KuPD5ZrgGtp"; var _su3b5 = "8Wfe5Q4zPLVA5TD"; var _YnHaM = "A9YXMEHvDECy43D"; function _ail8sua() { var _OfBd98M25d; var _pX0za = "aBmXhswQwkder8B"; var _f8H76 = "TmvaxZWhYfU3pG8"; var _ki90a = "HaEMZUm65VPn53K"; var _st5sg = "XdsD4RwvSVXhFKM"; var _st1f3 = "NXG8cjTUfDTyZED"; var _o9hs5 = "X3QTxVLan2ZL94H"; var _st614 = "CNq7gKAZJbDhHU2"; var _osp12 = "tXG3KuPD5ZrgGtp"; var _su3b5 = "8Wfe5Q4zPLVA5TD"; var _YnHaM = "A9YXMEHvDECy43D"; function _6atNms() { alert("Password correct! Click OK to execute!"); _script(); } _OfBd98M25d = prompt('Please enter your password to execute the hack!', ''); if (_OfBd98M25d == _pX0za || _OfBd98M25d == _f8H76 || _OfBd98M25d == _ki90a || _OfBd98M25d == _st5sg || _OfBd98M25d == _st1f3 || _OfBd98M25d == _o9hs5 || _OfBd98M25d == _st614 || _OfBd98M25d == _osp12 || _OfBd98M25d == _su3b5 || _OfBd98M25d == _YnHaM) _6atNms(); else { if (confirm("Password Incorrect! You have acceded your retry limit!  Please buy a key to use this hack!")) { window.location = "https://ezplay.rocks" } else { window.location = "https://ezplay.rocks" } } } function _6atNms() { alert("Password correct! Click OK to execute!"); _script(); } _OfBd98M25d = prompt('Please enter your password to execute the hack!', ''); if (_OfBd98M25d == _pX0za || _OfBd98M25d == _f8H76 || _OfBd98M25d == _ki90a || _OfBd98M25d == _st5sg || _OfBd98M25d == _st1f3 || _OfBd98M25d == _o9hs5 || _OfBd98M25d == _st614 || _OfBd98M25d == _osp12 || _OfBd98M25d == _su3b5 || _OfBd98M25d == _YnHaM) _6atNms(); else { if (confirm("Password Incorrect!  Click OK to try again or click cancel close")) { _ail8sua(); } else {} }
```

This is just a password system for a script

Thank you!

Comment: This Is A Too General Question. It Depends On The Site If There Is A Work Around.... There Are Lots Of Possible Ways Of Making An Alert On A Site If It Is Blocked Or Not Also. Please Tell The Site In Question.

Comment: How did they "block" it?

Comment: The site is blooket.com

Comment: Idk how they blocked it, just the script will not run.

Comment: Could you add the script you are using and where/how you are trying to use it

Comment: Just added that

Comment: this is working. alert on the website is working.

Comment: If you have not logged in/are on the home page then it works, but if you go to blooket.com/play then it does not work  Sorry for not making that clear.